# calling a method of an Activity from a Service

Tags: android, service

I created a service and I called `getMessage()` method of XMPPClient Activity like this

```
if ((XMPPClient.inChating)){
  XMPPClient xmpp=new XMPPClient();
  xmpp.getMessage(message);
}
```

but there was no result.

How to call that methode from that service?

Comment: What do you mean "no result"? Does it even build? Have you debugged this? Was null returned or...?

Comment: that method was doesnot called

Comment: It is not a valid vay to start activity. Is XMPPClient active - passed onCreate() - when you call getMessage()?

Comment: You're going to need to give more precise details about what you're doing. You said the method's not getting called- this means inChating must be set to false, no? Have you step debugged this?

Comment: Please post the answer for others who may encounter the same problem...

Comment: either use interface or use broadcast receiver for that

Answer (score 0):

You'd better send a broadcast to notify the activity to do something.

It's not good to call the methods in activity because you don't know the state of the activity.